# Using devise_token_auth with form auth

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise, token, rails-4-2-1

I'm trying to allow using on mobile devices to be authenticated using a token, while still using the webforms for the web application. I decided to use [devise_token_auth](https://github.com/lynndylanhurley/devise_token_auth). Whenever I try and start the application I get an error because a session path is already defined.

#### error

```
ArgumentError: Invalid route name, already in use: 'new_provider_session'
```

#### config/routes.rb

```
mount_devise_token_auth_for 'Provider', at: 'api/v1/auth'
  devise_for :providers, controllers: {} do
    get 'providers/sign_in', to: 'web/sessions#new'
    delete 'providers/sign_out', to: 'web/sessions#destroy'
  end
  root to: 'web/welcome#welcome'

  devise_for :admins, controllers: {} do
    get 'admins/sign_in', to: 'web/sessions#new'
    delete 'admins/sign_out', to: 'web/sessions#destroy'
  end
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try this:

Generate the Provider resource with the `devise_token_auth` generator

```
$ rails g devise_token_auth:install Provider auth
```

then change the `config/routes.rb` for placing this routes inside the namespaces for API versioning

```
namespace :api do
  namespace :v1 do
    mount_devise_token_auth_for 'Provider', at: 'auth'
  end
end
```

Check the routes

```
$ rake routes
```